# How to add value from Json into a list object using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, oop, object-object-mapping

I have a class `User` and a `List` like this:

```
List<User> users = List();

class User {
  int id;
  String name;

  User({this.id, this.name});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      id: json["id"] as int,
      name: json["name"] as String
    );
  }
}
```

and a Json Data like below:

```
  var DataUser= [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Leanne"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Graham"}
  ];
```

How can I add value from `DataUser` into `List<User> users`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the `List` of `json objects` and use your `User.fromJson` to convert each `json object` to a `User object`.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
List<User> users = List();

  var DataUser = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Leanne"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Graham"}
  ];

  List<User> getUsersFromJson() {
    // iterate through the list of json
    for (var json in DataUser) 
    // add the user object to your list
    users.add(User.fromJson(json));
    // return the list of users
    return users;
  }
```